# No suitable driver found for jdbc in java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection

Im new in sql server, and want to create connection between java and sql server. my connection code is:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con;
       try {

       String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://HELLO-PC:1433; databaseName=Attendance Teachers;";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "", "");
        System.out.println("connected");
        java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();    
      }
        catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(AttendanceTeachers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

my server name is 'HELLO-PC' an i also add sqljdbc.jar. i see error:

```
Feb 01, 2013 11:24:46 AM attendance.teachers.AttendanceTeachers main
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://HELLO-PC:1433;   databaseName=Attendance Teachers;
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at attendance.teachers.AttendanceTeachers.main(AttendanceTeachers.java:30)
```

I realy need help.thanks.

Comment: before use connection you need to initialize jdbc driver Class.forName("driver name")

Comment: i add that and i see this error:

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.

Comment: what kind of database do you use? Microsoft, Oracle, DB2, Firebird? You need to use the correct jar for the database and as Georgy said initialize

Comment: Well the message "*server version is not supported*" is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is cleare. but i dont know witch jar file i should use to support it sql server 2008.

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov that is a myth. You don't need to do any such thing. The only reason to load the class manually is to cause an exception to be thrown on startup for lazy initialized connections.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question so it suddenly becomes an entirely different question. I will rollback your last edit that changed the exception. Please open a new question (if you really don't get the new error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to do this:

```
private final String dbDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

try {
    Class.forName(dbDriver).newInstance(); // use java reflection to load the database driver
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("failure");
}
```

Comment: I have news for you. This does absolutely nothing useful towards solving the problem, except that you'll throw an exception earlier than when you use the driver class. It is not necessary to do this. For some reason many examples on the web do this, but it's not necessary - the class loader will find the class without this code

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not in the code, it's that the jar file containing the JDBC driver class for sqlserver is not in the classpath when you execute your program.

Visit the appropriate sqlserver web site (google) and download the JDBC driver jar and put it in your build path if executing in an IDE, or in the same directory as your program jar if executing from the command line.

Comment: i add jdbc.jar file in 'add external jars' from project properties . i also use netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will normally occur when you are using a older verison of JDBC driver if you are working with JDBC 4.0

When you download the SQlserver JDBC driver from the Microsoft website, you will get two jar files: sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc.jar.

1.sqljdbc.jar: Provides support for JDBC 3.0 specification

2.sqljdbc4.jar: Provides support for JDBC 4.0 specification

So.check with sqljdbc4.jar